# How to split a text into an array of sentences (separated by full stop, comma, question mark etc) using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split the content of an article into its sentences.
For example, Splitting

```
"Hi, My Name is Mark. I am going to the store, Do you need anything?"
```

to an array like

```
["Hi," , "My Name is Mark." , "I am going to the store," , "Do you need anything?"]
```

Could you help with the code using `split()` ?

Comment: and where exactly is your problem, when using `split`? (i can see a few potential ones, but what is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = "Hi, My Name is Mark. I am going to the store, Do you need anything?",
    strArray = str.split(/[,.]/),
    spliterArray = str.match(/[,.]/g),
    newArray = [];

for (let [key, val] of strArray.entries()) {
  let splitVal = spliterArray[key] ? spliterArray[key] : "";
  newArray.push(val.trim() + splitVal);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)